# PyCharm won't let me change the line spacing in the terminal

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to modify the line spacing in the terminal window because it's just too spaced out for me to comfortably read on a smaller monitor. I believe I've found the appropriate settings page:
[image]

The minimum line spacing it allows me to set is 0.6, although I'd prefer 0, this is fine.

The problem however is that even when I reload the PyCharm window, the terminal spacing is still atrocious:

[image]

If anything it looks like it's worse than it was before, like the spacing is still at font size 12 while everything else is font size 10.

Why won't PyCharm let me change the line spacing in the terminal? What do I have to do to make this look more readable?